# data sharing dropWhile function in scala using pattern matching

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching, data-sharing

Suppose you have the following functions available for reference

```
sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
```

Now consider the following `dropWhile` function which supposedly
removes elements from `List` prefix as long as they match a predicate.

```
def dropWhile[A](l: List[A], f: A => Boolean): List[A] =
  l match {
    case Cons(h, t) if f(h) => dropWhile(t, f)
    case _ => l
  }
```

I have the following test cases:

```
dropWhile(List(1, 2, 3), (x: Int) => x < 2) shouldBe List(2, 3)

dropWhile(List(1, 2, 3), (x: Int) => x > 2) shouldBe List(1, 2)

dropWhile(List(1, 2, 3), (x: Int) => x > 0) shouldBe Nil

dropWhile(Nil, (x: Int) => x > 0) shouldBe Nil
```

**Question?**

Test case (2) **fails**. Why is that the case?. The interpreter
actually gives me `List(1, 2, 3)` the original list without having
dropped anything.

For context this is *Exercise 3.5 on Functional Programming in Scala*
by Chuisano and Bjarnason. The authors themselves implement this
function exactly the same way I have written on here. Is there
something that I am not understanding here?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test case (2) is wrong. You are dropping elements while `x > 2`. Since the first element fails this test, it does not drop anything. So `List(1, 2, 3)` is the correct result.

The test case appears to be testing for `filterNot` not `dropWhile`.

Comment: Yeah  you are right. Is there a way to modify this function so that the test case passes?. Surely, the authors mean it this way.

Comment: `filterNot` is different from `dropWhile` because you need to build a new list rather than just truncate the old one,  so you need to re-write the function rather than just modify it.

Comment: Got it. I have misunderstood the question I guess. The function does exactly what it is supposed to do.